# venn diagrams - How can this event be shown?

Tags: statistics

I have this venn diagram [image]

For which i have shade (A ∩ B ) ∪ C. I see where A and B intersect, but i don't how a union should appear between the intersection and C.  Could someone clarify where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red area is $(A\cap B)\cup C$

[image: AB + C]

The red points are the ones that are either in the intersection $A\cap B$, or in $C$ (or in both, but there are no such points in this case). That's what union *means*, after all.

Comment: So something like  A ∩ ( B  ∪ C)’ would look like this http://snag.gy/lxUmu.jpg

Comment: @stats Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

You simply shade $A \cap B$ which is the common area for $A$ and $B$, then you shade $C$ too because in a way you're "combining the two sets". All of what's in $A \cap B$ AND in $C$ is in the union.